# Proper treatment of Chalazion draining

Tags: infection, ophthalmology, eyelids

I have had a Chalazion on my left upper eyelid for about a month now. It had been growing larger, and recently started to form a white head.

I get styes and chalazions fairly frequently, but never this large. I even had one on the other eye that complicated into a diagnosis of conjunctival pyogenic granuloma (excision surgery was recommended, but the tumor went away on it's own after a couple months).

My current chalazion is draining as we speak...

**What can I do to prevent infection?**

- Keep applying warm compress?
- Saline solution?
- Is it necessary to visit the ophthalmologist to get a topical antibiotic, or should I wait to see if signs of infection show?

[Chalazion Photo http://i.share.pho.to/59dc1e8b_l.jpeg](http://i.share.pho.to/59dc1e8b_l.jpeg)

Comment: Optometrists may be able to help, but I think you might mean "opthalmologist". Optometrists are the good folks who make eyeglasses. Opthalmologists deal with issuea which mat result in recurrent chalazions.

Comment: I've had those damn things but never had one drain so I don't know the answer, but if I had infectious material draining into my eye I would want some antibiotic coverage.

Comment: Thanks - that was my exact line of thought, but I decided to monitor the eye closely and so far it has been doing very well. I have a small 'scab' on the eyelid but every day the eye is less swollen.

Comment: Hi there, this seems like it's asking for personal diagnosis, but is dancing on the line of general treatment for Chalazion. Could you please add a definition for chalazion and then reword the question to reflect a more general question? Then we may be able to address it.